# How can I send umlauts to a smartphone with a GSM module?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial, gsm, at-command

I build a SMS-Server on a Raspberry Pi 4B connected to a GSM-Module with Python. This is the GSM-Module I use: [Waveshare Wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM800C_GSM/GPRS_HAT#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi). I can send SMS to my customers infoming them about there order.

My Problem is that I can't send *"Umlauts"* like `"ÄäÖöÜü"` and specific characters like `"ß"`. Whenever I try to send them to my own Phone they get replaced by other characters.
For example an `"ä"` gets replaced by `"@¤"`.

Im using `AT+CSCS="GSM"` to set the Module to the GSM Character set and `AT+CMGF=1` to send the SMS in clean text.
My main Question is: does anyone know what I can try to send the umlauts correctly?

The umlauts are all correctly transferred to the SMS server and the server then sends them to the GSM module using the pySerial library.
`serial.write(sms_text.encode('utf-8'))`

I thought maybe the character set of the GSM module does not have the umlauts. Does each GSM module have its own character set or is there a standard for it?

Comment: What GSM module are you using? Does it support UCS2 character set? Check it by issuing test command `AT+CSCS=?`

Comment: I linked the GSM-Module in description. Here is the link again: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM800C_GSM/GPRS_HAT#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi

I will try the AT command soon and will give you more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [SIM 800 AT command manual](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf), at paragraph 3.2.12, the module supports the following character sets:

> **"GSM"**  - GSM 7 bit default alphabet (3GPP TS 23.038);
> **"UCS2"** - 16-bit universal multiple-octet coded character set (ISO/IEC10646); UCS2 character strings are converted to hexadecimal numbers from 0000 to FFFF; e.g. "004100620063" equals three 16-bit characters with decimal values 65, 98 and 99
> **"IRA"**  - International reference alphabet (ITU-T T.50)
> **"HEX"**  - Character strings consist only of hexadecimal bers from 00 to FF;
> **"PCCP"** - PC character set Code
> **"PCDN"** - PC Danish/Norwegian character set "8859-1"  ISO 8859 Latin 1 character set

In your case, I would try at least two options:

1. **PCDN** - Danish/Norwegian character set

   Send command

   ```
    AT+CSCS="PCDN"
   ```

   and write normally the characters into serial port. This character set supports the characters you need, as explained in this [code chart](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp865.html).
2. **UCS2** - Unicode

   Send command

   ```
    AT+CSCS="UCS2"
   ```

   and, for each character you need to print, write to serial the corresponding 4 hexadecimal characters corresponding to its code, as you can find in the following [code chart](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html).
   For example, character `Ö` can be obtained by writing to `+CMGS` command the code `00D6`.

If the first solution works you are fine. The second solution has the drawback to require the encoding of each character to be sent, but makes you ready to support almost every character set in the world.

Comment: Just to emphasize the last point: After you run `AT+CSCS="UCS2"` **every single string from that point in time must be encoded that way** (until a new AT+CSCS value). So for instance to switch from UCS2 to UTF-8 would be `AT+CSCS="005500540046002D0038"`.